# How do I print the contents of a files in a directory but ignore files which are opened in write mode?

Tags: go

I have a goroutine which periodically checks for new files in a directory and then prints the contents of the files. However there is another goroutine which creates a file, writes contents into it and then saves the file.

How do I ignore the files which are open in WRITE mode in a directory?

Sample Code:

```
for {
 fileList, err := ioutil.ReadDir("/uploadFiles")
  if err != nil {
     log.Fatal(err)
     continue
  }

 for _, f := range fileList {
      log.Println("File : ", f.Name())
      go printContents(f.Name())
 }

 time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

In the printContents goroutine I want to ignore the files which are open in WRITE mode.

Comment: There is no automatic way to do this. You'll have to keep track of which files you have open in write mode, and exclude them.

Comment: BTW, there's never any reason to use `continue` (or anything else) after `log.Fatal`, because `log.Fatal` causes the program to exit.

Comment: Its a oversight.    Regarding the file in write mode, what happens if the file writer is a seperate go application ? I guess I am trying to find if there is any way we can know that fact.

Comment: Moving files into the directory after they are completely written isn't an option?

Comment: Most software seems to use a temporary upload directory. Or names the files something with ".part" or ".partial" on the end. In both cases the file is renamed when it is complete. Otherwise, other software has no way to know if the file is completely uploaded or not.

Comment: If the writer is a separate application, the problem is the same, and the solution will just require some sort of inter-process communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not how it's done.

Off the top of my head I can think of these options:

- If both goroutines are working in the same program,
  there is little problem: make the "producer" goroutine register
  the names of the files it *has completed* modifying into some
  registry, and make the "consumer" goroutine read (and delete)
  from that registry.

  In the simplest case that could be a buffered channel.

  If the producer works much faster than the consumer,
  and you don't want to block the former for some reason
  then a slice protected by a mutex would fit the bill.
- If the goroutines work in different processes on the same
  machine but you control both programs, make the producer
  process communicate the same data to the consumer process
  via any suitable sort of IPC.

  What method to do IPC is better depends on how the
  processes start up, interact etc.

  There is a wide variety of options.
- If you control both processes but do not want to mess with
  IPC between them (there are reasons, too), then make the producer
  follow best practices on how to write a file
  (more on this in a moment), and make the consumer use any
  filesystem-monitoring facility to report which files get created ("appear") once produced by the producer.
  You may start with [`github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify`](https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify).

  To properly write a file, the producer have to write its
  data to a temporary file—that is, a file located in the same
  directory but having a filename which is well understood to
  indicate that the file is not done with yet—for instance,
  ".foobar.data.part" or "foobar.data.276gd14054.tmp" is OK for writing "foobar.data".
  (Other approaches exist but this one is good enough to
  start with.)

  Once the file is ready, the producer have to rename the
  file from its temporary name to its "proper", final name.
  This operation is atomic on all sensible OSes/filesystems,
  and makes file atomically "spring into existense" from the PoV
  of the consumer. For instance, [`inotify` on Linux generates
  an event of type "moved to" for such an appearance](https://manpages.debian.org/7/inotify).

  If you don't feel like doing the proper thing yourself, [`github.com/dchest/safefile`](https://github.com/dchest/safefile) is a good cross-platform start.

  As you can see, with this approach you know
  the file is done just from the fact it was reported
  to having appeared.
- If you do not control the producer, you may need to resort to
  guessing.

  The simpest is to, again, monitor the filesystem for
  events—but this time for "file updated" events, not "file created"
  events. For each file reported as updated you had to remember
  the timestamp of that event, and when certain amount of time passes, you may *declare* that the file is done by the producer.

  IMO this approach is the worst of all, but if you have no
  better options it's at least something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is really helpful